# Bigcommerce - Update Price of Products in Cart Based on Price List & Custom Fields

Tags: bigcommerce

With Bigcommerce Price Lists, we obviously have the ability to give discounts based on bulk buys/qty.

We want to be able to combine the quantities of items in the cart if the products have a common custom field (or similar) and give the bulk price list discounts based on the combined qty.

For example:

Product A has a bulk purchase discount - buy 5+ and get 10% discount
Product B has a bulk purchase discount - buy 10+ and get 15% discount
Both these products would have a custom field/meta field at the variant level that = "Allow Combined Discount A"

So that means if Product A has a cart qty of 4, and product B has a cart qty of 6, the combined qty = 10

Product A should receive 10% discount (as combined qty >=5)
Product B should receive 15% discount (as combined qty >=10)

How can we achieve this? Ideally, the price updates/discounts would apply immediately when the cart quantities reach the correct levels. There could also be other products in the cart with different combining custom field/meta field values, which would need to calculate their own total - e.g. "Allow Combined Discount B"

Promotions on categories will not work as there are can be varients on products a and b where the bulk discounts do not apply, or the qty of some variants should not count towards a combined total to apply price list bulk buy discounts.

Comment: Hey DaleP, have you considered utilizing the automatic promotions feature instead of price lists? From here you can accomplish very specific targeted promotions, and can stack promotions/use multiple/etc.... 

I'd recommend you to take a look a the documentation on Automatic Promotions (https://support.bigcommerce.com/s/article/Automatic-Promotions) to see if it may be a better fit for your requirement.

Comment: Hi @HeatherBarr - This won't work for us as we have 15,000+ customers - all potentially with different pricing - this is where price lists come in - a price list for every customer. From my testing, any promotions on top of price lists can potentially double discounts given. I can not see any way that auto promotions can cater to my scenario anyway as the only possible solution is to use discounts for products in a category - this doesn't work as some of the varients on the product should not get the discount. There are too many varients/products to use exclusions.